# cusotmize nvd3 multi line chart legend click

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using nvd3 to create multi line chart.

There are 6 items in my nvd3 line chart (Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5, Item6).

I need to customize click on legend so that:

a) clicking on 'Item1' or 'Item2' legend will enable/disable both Item1 & Item2

b) the same for each item pair (item1/item2; item3/item4; item5/item6)

I have no idea how to do this. If this is possible then I believe there should be event that I have to listen for and then customize it, but I cannot find it.

Comment: It sounds like you would need to change the NVD3 source.

Comment: Ok, if I have to change it, can you point what shoild I look for? Some events, which events? Or something?

Comment: The code for the legend.